# Page Counter not working ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, web

everybody. I've been trying to follow exactly what it says in my textbook, but to no avail. Now, my problem is that I'm currently attempting to make a page counter to keep track of how many times each page has been accessed, then display each value on a new page.

Here is the C# Counter code which is the same for all pages:

```
int sessionCount = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["CountMain"] == null)
            sessionCount = 0;
        else
            sessionCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CountMain"]);
        sessionCount++;
    }
    protected void Page_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session["CountMain"] = sessionCount;
    }
```

The prerender is something I added in myself after research on the internet, and in the textbook. No luck.

Here is the Counter Page C# code:

```
public partial class Counter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int sessionCount = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sessionMain = Session["CountMain"].ToString();
        string sessionComment = Session["CountComment"].ToString();
        string sessionCompleted = Session["CountCompleted"].ToString();
        string sessionCurrent = Session["CountCurrent"].ToString();
        string sessionAbout = Session["CountAbout"].ToString();
        string sessionContact = Session["CountContact"].ToString();
        string sessionCounter = Session["CountCounter"].ToString();

        if (Session["CountCounter"] == null)
            sessionCount = 0;
        else
            sessionCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CountCounter"]);
        sessionCount++;

        lblAboutCount.Text = sessionAbout;
        lblCommentCount.Text = sessionComment;
        lblCompletedCount.Text = sessionCompleted;
        lblContactCount.Text = sessionContact;
        lblCounterCount.Text = sessionCounter;
        lblCurrentCount.Text = sessionCurrent;
        lblMainCount.Text = sessionMain;
    }
```

When I try to run it, I get a "NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code, Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Error.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT #1**

Okay, Thanks to Hexxangonal, the counter is now working. However, my Counter Page is now counting it self by 2 times. (incrementing by 2 every time it loads)

```
public partial class Counter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int sessionCount = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["CountCounter"] == null)
        {
            sessionCount = 0;
            Session["CountCounter"] = sessionCount;
        }
        else
        {
            sessionCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CountCounter"]);
            sessionCount++;
            Session["CountCounter"] = sessionCount;
        }

        Session["CountCounter"] = sessionCount;

        lblAboutCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CountAbout"]);
        lblCommentCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CountComment"]);
        lblCompletedCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CountCompleted"]);
        lblContactCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CountContact"]);
        lblCounterCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CountCounter"]);
        lblCurrentCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CountCurrent"]);
        lblMainCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CountMain"]);
    }
```

Comment: Which line is giving you the trouble? What object are you expecting? Where does it get passed from?

Comment: Ah, thanks for reminding me. 

lblAboutCount.Text = sessionAbout;

is where the exception hits. I'm trying to get the Session["Count???"] to pass through to the values on the Counter page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The NullReference exception is probably coming from one of your `Session["CountXXXXX"].ToString()`  lines (CountXXXXX is one of your count objects like `CountMain`) because `Session["CountXXXXX"]` does not exist (it is null).

You can actually simplify that page to the following logic and you will bypass the issue as the null will just be assigned to the string variable.

```
public partial class Counter : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    int sessionCount = 0;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["CountCounter"] == null)
            sessionCount = 0;
        else
            sessionCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CountCounter"]);
        sessionCount++;

        // **NEW** Save the new count value
        Session["CountCounter"] = sessionCount;

        lblAboutCount.Text = Session["CountAbout"];
        lblCommentCount.Text = Session["CountComment"];
        lblCompletedCount.Text = Session["CountCompleted"];
        lblContactCount.Text = Session["CountContact"];
        lblCounterCount.Text = sessionCounter;
        lblCurrentCount.Text = Session["CountCurrent"];
        lblMainCount.Text = Session["CountMain"];
    }
```

There was also an issue where you were mixing integers and strings with the `sessionCount` variable with a member variable and a local variable (respectively).  I have cleaned this up.

Comment: Ah, you're also not restoring that sessionCount value!

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and assume I won't be needing the PreRender method?

Comment: No, there's no need to store that Session variable there. Especially if your book doesn't mention it. You can use it if you want, but you might as well stick all of the logic in your Load.

Comment: If I might mention, on your lblAboutCount.Text = Session["CountAbout"]; lines, you might want to change that to lblAboutCount.Text = Convert.ToString(Session["CountAbout"]);

Comment: Ah, I was assuming it was a string.  ToString should also work there then.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with these two lines

```
   if (Session["CountCounter"] == null)
        sessionCount = 0;
    else
        sessionCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CountCounter"]);
    sessionCount++;
```

You are not putting back these values into the session variable.
You should be doing as follows:-

```
    if (Session["CountCounter"] == null)
    {
        sessionCount = 0;
        Session["CountCounter"]=sessionCount;
    }
    else
    {
        sessionCount = Convert.ToInt32(Session["CountCounter"]);
        sessionCount++;
        Session["CountCounter"]=sessionCount;
     }
```

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy but are you counting for individual user or for every user.

Comment: Just how many times the page is visited, so I would guess every user.

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy then your approach is wrong. because session is individual to user. it's not common to every user. You should be using application variable rather than session.

Comment: @RionMurphMurphy here is good link this may be useful to you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14034288/asp-net-and-c-sharp-page-view-counter-using-a-database